# Use services in angular js to get and set a variable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a service function as show below

```
.service('ItemService', ['$http', function ($http) {
     var items = [{'item_id': '1', 'item_name': 'abc'}];
        return {
           getItems: function () {
               return items;
               },
          setItems: function (value) {
              items = value;
          }
   };
 }]);
```

This code is working fine, I want to make the items dynamic, For example

```
var items =   $http({
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'http://localhost/app/item/get/10',
}).then(function (response) {
   return response.data;
});
```

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You service will be like this

```
.service('ItemService', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        getItems: function(id) {
            return $http({
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost/app/item/get/' + id,
            })
        },
        setItems: function(items) {
            return $http({
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/app/item/' + items,
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

And you should call it inside you controller like this

```
ItemService.getItems().then(function(response){
    //Retrieve the data
    $scope.items = response.items;
}, function(error){
    //Handle the errors
})
```

Comment: I want my service exactly like this

Comment: But I want to replace items only

Comment: I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

```
.service('ItemService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    // I want to initialize this items array before I call getItems funtion, Anyway to do the same? 
    var items = [{'item_id': '1', 'item_name': 'abc'}];

       //Below section I want exactly same I will change items array from my controller and also I will use getItem again to get this items array agian. My getItems should only return the items array
      return {
       getItems: function () {
           return items;
           },
      setItems: function (value) {
          items = value;
    }
 };
}]);
```